# How to host a dynamic web application of Firebase ? Especially for encryption and decryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, encryption, web-applications

I am trying to do encryption and decryption on firebase hosting so that the crucial details remain hidden from the client. I am trying to host an app on the firebase hosting so that all the API calls, encryption, and decryption is done on the firebase.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to implement your API calls as Google Cloud Functions that respond to HTTP triggers (see documentation at [https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)).  Each API endpoint would be one cloud function.

Within the cloud functions, you can do whatever encryption/decryption is necessary before storing or after retrieving data from Firebase or Firestore or Cloud Storage or whatever else you are using.